pgAdmin 4: How can I change the default starting value of sequences?
I don't like sequences starting from 1 while vectors, arrays etc. start from 0. Having sequences start from 0 makes it easier to store the rows in a container easier.
Each time I create a table in pgAdmin 4 that has an auto-incrementing sequence, I have to change the starting value manually.
Is there any way to modify pgAdmin 4 so it starts sequences from 0 instead of 1?

Kinda related note: pgAdmin 4 has an annoying 'bug'. If you want to
change the starting sequence these are the steps:
-Open properties.
-Change the minimum value from 1 to 0.
-Save the changes, which closes the properties panel.
-Open the panel again and set the minimum value to 0.
If you try to do these in a single step, it says "starting value cannot be less than
minimum value". This is why I want to modify it, so I don't have to deal with this every single time.


In postgresql, by default, arrays start from 1 so does sequences.

I'm asking if there is any way to change the default.
